# Mirror data in Kafka 0.8.2.1 cluster to Kafka 2.2.0 cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, replication

I wanted use Apache Spark Structured Streaming along with Kafka, Spark Structured Streaming Supports Kafka 0.10 and above and my Kafka cluster uses kafka version 0.8.2.1 . I want to replicate some of the topics from current kafka 0.8.2.1 cluster to new Kafka Cluster which is based on 2.2.0.

To do this i tried using kafka-console-consumer on Kafka 2.2.0 cluster to listen the messages from kafka cluster 0.8.2.1 and piped the result of kafka-console-consumer to kafka-console-producer on the the kafka 2.2.0 cluster. But that didn't  kafka-console-consumer on Kafka 2.2.0 cluster was not able to receive any messages.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I have solved this problem by reading the data from kafka 0.8.2.1 cluster using the Java Client APIs and I am writing the data read from older kafka cluster(0.8.2.1) to newer kafka cluster(2.2.0) using the client APIs.

Can anyone suggest some better ways to mirror two kafka clusters running different versions of Kafka?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330